Print the excel sheet ending with suffix "_graph" when button is pressed
I am trying to print all the sheets ending with suffix _graph to pdf. However, it gives me the errror of No sheets with suffix '_graph' found. What I am missing here?
Code:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PrintFile As String
    Dim GraphSheets As Collection
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim i As Integer

    PrintFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\level_graph.pdf"
    Set GraphSheets = New Collection

    ' Loop through all worksheets and collect sheets with suffix "_graph"
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Right(ws.Name, 6) = "_graph" Then
            GraphSheets.Add ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn back on error handling

    ' Check if there are any sheets found
    If GraphSheets.Count > 0 Then
        ' Select the sheets to print
        For i = 1 To GraphSheets.Count
            Sheets(GraphSheets(i)).Select (i = 1)
        Next i

        ' Export the selected sheets as PDF
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=PrintFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Else
        MsgBox "No sheets with suffix '_graph' found.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub

Error:

level1_graph :


Add Debug.Print ws.Name, Right(ws.Name, 6), (Right(ws.Name, 6) = "_graph") after For Each .. line to validate sheets' name.

@taller I tried the Debug line too but no avail.

What's the output (pls edit your post to share it)? Is there any invisible character in sheet name?

Change ThisWorkbook.Worksheets to ThisWorkbook.Sheets if *_graph is a chart. btw, Avoid using "On Error Resume Next" unless you are certain that a specific error is being intentionally ignored.

@taller the sheet name is as it on the screenshot pasted above in the question but in the *_graph sheet there is a chart as I pasted in the question. I have edited the question but also it says error Type mismatch.

Export Matching Sheets to PDF
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const DST_FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\level_graph.pdf"
    Const SHEET_NAME_PATTERN As String = "*_graph"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this cod
    
    ' Reference the workbook's active sheet (to be reselected finally).
    Dim ash As Object: Set ash = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    ' Return the matching sheet names in the keys of a dictionary.
    ' The keys of a dictionary are a 1D array (so are the items).
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim sh As Object
    
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If sh.Name Like SHEET_NAME_PATTERN Then dict.Add sh.Name, Empty
    Next sh
    
    ' Exit if no sheets found.
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No sheets matching the pattern """ & SHEET_NAME_PATTERN _
            & """ in workbook """ & wb.Name & """ found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Reference and select the sheets to export.
    Dim shs As Sheets: Set shs = wb.Sheets(dict.Keys)
    wb.Activate
    shs.Select
    
    ' Export as PDF.
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=DST_FILE_PATH, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
    ' Select the initially active sheet.
    ash.Select
        
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "The following sheets were exported to PDF:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Join(dict.Keys, vbLf), vbInformation

End Sub

